# Adding column to datagradview from different datasource

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview, datasource

I'm currently working on an "advanced" search form for my application. I'm using a `datagridview` to display the results. The idea is to be able to search thoroughly (with lots of options).

Currently I fill the datagridview like this:

```
    dgvData.AutoGenerateColumns = false;

        if (cbbKlant.SelectedItem != null)
        {
            dgvData.DataSource = StatistiekManagement.getOpdrachten((klant)cbbKlant.SelectedItem);

            //ID kolom
            DataGridViewTextBoxColumn id = new DataGridViewTextBoxColumn();
            id.Name = "ID";
            id.DataPropertyName = "opdracht_id";

            //Plaatsen kolom
            DataGridViewTextBoxColumn plaatsen = new DataGridViewTextBoxColumn();
            plaatsen.Name = "Plaatsen";
            plaatsen.DataPropertyName = "aantal_personen";

            //Vertrekplaats kolom
            DataGridViewTextBoxColumn vertrek = new DataGridViewTextBoxColumn();
            vertrek.Name = "Vertrek";
            vertrek.DataPropertyName = "locatie_id";

            this.dgvData.Columns.Add(id);
            this.dgvData.Columns.Add(plaatsen);
            this.dgvData.Columns.Add(vertrek);
        }
```

My problem here is I want to add information to the `datagridview` from another table. For example: I have a `contract` and this contract has a `location`. How do I display the `location` into this `datagridview`?

I also use `LINQ TO SQL` to get my data from the database.

Thanks,
Thomas

Answer (score 1):

You can't bind a datagridview to two different sources.

The solution for you would be to write a SQL statement to join two different tables and then populate a dataset with that. You could then use that as your data source.

Comment: How do I return data from a joined LINQ statement? I wrote the following piece of linq code but I don't know how to return the query:             `var query = (from o in dc.opdrachts
                         where o.klant == klant
                         join lo in dc.locatie_opdrachts on o.opdracht_id equals lo.opdracht_id
                         select new { o, lo.locatie});`

Comment: I'm not sure. My LINQ is rusty to say the least. Couldn't you just call a SQL join against your SQL connection and use that dataset?

Answer (score 1):

There are several ways to attach the location. The easiest would be if you could add the Location as a property to the bound baseclass. It doesn't have to be a field in the database, just a property you could bind to. If inheriting isn't an option, sometimes encapsulation can work.

Besides the above, you can always add a non-bound column to your (bound) datagridview. The value which it should display, could come from any source you like. One of the ways to display the value is to use the datagridview's cellformatting event:

```
        //inside initialization void
        dgvData.CellFormatting+=new DataGridViewCellFormattingEventHandler(dgvData_CellFormatting);
        dvcol = new DataGridViewTextBoxColumn();
        dgvData.Columns.Add(dvcol);
    }

    DataGridViewColumn dvcol;

    void dgvData_CellFormatting(object sender, DataGridViewCellFormattingEventArgs e)
    {
        if (dvcol != null && e.RowIndex != -1 && e.ColumnIndex == dvcol.Index)//where Column1 is your combobox column
        {
            var rec = (YourRecordTypeSuchAsContract)dgvData.Rows[e.RowIndex].DataBoundItem;
            e.Value = ""; //get description based on the rec
        }
    }
```

Comment: Thanks, how exactly do I add a property to my bound baseclass? I let LINQ create all the classes.

Comment: Extending auto generated LINQ class is actually very easy, because of the partial declaration they implement. If you go to the code behind (right-click on the table in designer and click 'view code'), you should see a partial class where you can add the properties. (As long as those properties don't have a columnattribute, they won't be considered part of the database schema).

Comment: Some links: short example here: http://www.dotnetguy.co.uk/post/2009/05/13/custom-properties-on-a-linq-2-sql-model/  And a longer tutorial here: http://www.sexyselect.net/blog/post/2011/06/24/Extending-Linq-2-Sql-Classes-adding-custom-properties